# I have a simple question about JavaScript type

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen that many site use use the `type` attribute in a `script` tag like this:

```
<script type="02aa3743b2e6c0a724cb116b-text/javascript">
```

Now my question about the `type` attribute is - what do they mean and what purpose do they serve?

It looks very different from the "standard" `type` attribute values.

Comment: I have never seen this before.  The `type`  is mostly optional on scripts now anyway.  Where have you seen this?

Comment: It looks like the numbers you see on a minified file like "2.17dad8e4.chunk.js". But yes, I've never seen that on the type before.

Comment: any example of what yor saying

Comment: me too i never seen    basically  The type attribute is used to identify the language of script code embedded within script tag. This is specified as MIME Type

Comment: The answer is covered in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). Basically any non-standard value is handled the same way (see `type` attribute)

Comment: I think you missread your example and its the nonce

Comment: @Jamiec – That describes how the browser behaves, but not the motivation of the people who wrote this code (which we lack enough context to provide).

Answer (score 4):

A script tag with non standard type can actually be used as a template container for content.

Browsers will simply ignore the tag when the type is non standard so html inside it will just be text and will not get rendered as DOM elements either.

There is no way to know what the naming convention used in your example refers to. One possibility would be a framework that uses unique identifiers to track templates for various parts of an app, but this is simply a guess

Simple example of extracting content within such a tag.

```js
const html = document.querySelector('script[type^="02aa3743b2e6c0a724cb116b"]').innerHTML

document.body.innerHTML += 'From Script tag:' + html
```

```html
<script type="02aa3743b2e6c0a724cb116b-text/javascript">
  <h1> Script element Heading </h1>
</script>
```

Comment: While it *can* that's a very odd value to give to the type attribute when it is being used as such. Usually people have text/plain or template or similary.

Comment: @Quentin Convention does seem strange. Have any other theories?

Comment: Some, but they are *highly* speculative and I'd rather the OP gave full examples of use than air them on what information we have presently.

Comment: @charlietfl `<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000" data-ad-slot="000000"></ins>
<script type="1baf430ad51105b4e107a3e2-text/javascript">
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>`   can you tell me what they mean on here

Comment: Not really. Not sure how they would run that code other than getting it as text and using eval() which can be a security risk to use

Comment: @charlietfl please check the source code of this site for more details - `problogbooster.com` it has above 90 loading speed on mobile having google adsense!

Comment: I didn't go there but did figure out they could be reading that script content as text and creating another script element to insert it into and appending new element into page. I just tested it and got the code to run